# Using Specs with unitils

Tags: scala, specs, scalatest, unitils

I am trying to get scala specs and unitils-dbunit to work.

To use unitils you have to annotate your 
test class with @RunWith(classOf[UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner]) or
extend from a class and you can set DataSet's to load with
@DataSet(Array("DataSet.xml")). All of this works with JUnit.

But I got 2 problems when using specs:

- I am running my specs tests with gradle and the ScalaTestAntTask, so
  I guess the @RunWith annotation will be ignored.
- I can not set the @DataSet annotation to my test method as 
  seen here:

  ```
  [...]
  @RunWith(classOf[UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner])
  class DaoTest extends Specification with ScalaTest {

      @TestDataSource
      var dataSource: DataSource = null

      @DataSet(Array("DataSet.xml"))
      "querying the database" should {
          "return the right data" in {
              [assertSomething]
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This gives me the following compiler error:

error: expected start of definition

"querying the database" should {

^

Does somebody know how I can use specs and unitils together?

**UPDATE:** This is the solution I came up with:

```
    import org.specs.runner.ScalaTest
    import org.specs.Specification
    import org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule
    import java.io.File
    import java.util.Properties
    import org.unitils.core.ConfigurationLoader

    class DaoTest extends Specification with ScalaTest {

        "querying the database" should {

            doBefore {
                UnitilsDatabaseUtils.setup("DataSet.xml", "DataSet2.xml")
            }

            "return the right data" in {
                [test something]
            }
        }
    }

    object UnitilsDatabaseUtils {

        def setup(dataSetFileNames: String*) = {
            val configuration: Properties = new ConfigurationLoader().loadConfiguration
            val dbunitModule = new DbUnitModule
            dbunitModule.init(configuration)

            for (dataSetFileName <- dataSetFileNames) {
                val dataSetURL = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(dataSetFileName)
                dbunitModule.insertDataSet(new File(dataSetURL.toURI))
            }
        }
    }
```

--
 Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataSet annotation can't be applied directly to `"xxx" should` because this is not a test method, just a regular scala code call.

I can't give you a fully working solution but what you need to do is to dig out the unitils API and use the [DataSetFactory](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/dbunit/datasetfactory/impl/MultiSchemaXmlDataSetFactory.html) directly to load your data. I think that you can more or less reuse the code found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Testing/unitils/org/unitils/dbunit/DbUnitModule.java.htm).

Then, if you need to load this dataset before each example, just use a [doBefore](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/DeclareSpecifications#Call_a_function_before_or_after_each_example) call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked (I attached the solution to my question)